# Using RestKit 0.25 to parse local XML into CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, core-data, restkit

I'm trying to use RestKit to parse a local XML file into CoreData. I've done this successfully with online REST services, but parsing a local file or just parsing XML seems to be a completely different beast.

First I use a class named CoreDataHandler, which just encapsulates all the default CoreData stuff. So it's basically what xcode provides you with in the AppDelegate, put into a separate class.

What I've done so far:

```
CoreDataHandler* handler = [CoreDataHandler instance];

RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource* dataSource = [[RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:handler.managedObjectContext cache:sharedManager.managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache];
dataSource.operationQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];

NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Seed_010000" ofType:@"xml"];
NSData *sourceObject = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

RKObjectMapping* mapping = [self mapCourses];
RKMappingOperation* operation = [[RKMappingOperation alloc] initWithSourceObject:sourceObject destinationObject:nil mapping:mapping];
operation.dataSource = dataSource;

NSError* error = nil;
[operation performMapping:&error];

if( error == nil ) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [operation mappingInfo]);
    [handler saveContext];
} else {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
}
```

The mappings are created here:

```
+ (RKObjectMapping*) mapCourses {
    RKEntityMapping *courseMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForClass:[Course class]];
    [courseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"Name.text" : @"name" }];

    RKEntityMapping* sectionMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForClass:[Section class]];
    [sectionMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"order" : @"order",
                                                      @"Icon.text" : @"icon",
                                                      @"Name.text" : @"name",
                                                      @"Description.text" : @"desc" }];
    [courseMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"Sections" toKeyPath:@"sections" withMapping:sectionMapping]];

    return courseMapping;
}
```

The XML File looks like this:

```html
<MyProject>
  <Courses>
    <Course>
      <Name>Name of the Course</Name>
      <Sections>
        <Section order="0">
          <Icon>ICON_00</Icon>
          <Name>Name of the Section</Name>
          <Description>Description of the Section</Description>
        </Section>
      </Sections>
    </Course>
  </Courses>
</MyProject>
```

And the error I get is this:

```
2015-10-20 12:01:37.515 Training[16058:5400082] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSConcreteData 0x7fdf39f2b650> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Sections.'
```

The stack trace points at the [operation performMaping:&error]; line.

I hope anybody can shed some light on this.

EDIT: I changed the question, because the first error (about the wrong initialiser was due to my own stupidity. I used RKObjectMapping instead of RKEntityMapping, which you have to use when using CoreData.

Answer (score 1):

You look to have a couple of problems. It seems that you're using 2 different managed object contexts, one from the rest kit stack and one from your own stack. You shouldn't be creating any context of your own.

For your error, it's because you're using `RKObjectMapping` where you should be using `RKEntityMapping` because you're using Core Data.

Comment: First thing: You are right about the managed object context and I have cleaned that up by now. Don't know where that came from, some copy&paste error I guess.
For the second error, it's still there, even with RKEntityMapping.

Error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSConcreteData 0x7fdf39f2b650> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Sections.'

Comment: How did you define the mapping now? With the entity name?

Comment: Yes I will quickly update the question to show the changes.

Comment: You're still using the class, you need to use the entity: `mappingForEntityForName:inManagedObjectStore:`

Comment: No sorry, I just didn't update it all. This method doesn't even work on the EntityMapping. So I'm using the correct method and getting the error.

Comment: Not clear at all why your now getting an error related to an `NSData` instance. Turn on zombies to rule out memory issues.